# Is there an easier way to pass an array as command line argument using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration?

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line-arguments, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I am working on a .net generic host app and I would like to pass some configuation via command line and then bind it to an object:

```
public class CommandArgs
{
   public string Mode { get; set; }
   public string[] Logins { get; set; }
}
```

At this moment I know that I can pass the `Logins` array like that:

```
--CommandArgs:Logins:0=Login0 --CommandArgs:Logins:1=Login1 ...
```

The problem is the repeating number of '--CommandArgs:Logins:{index}' sentences.
I have tried to use switch mappings to reduce repeating sentences:

```
var switchMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   "--Logins", "CommandArgs:Logins"
};
    
    configBuilder.AddCommandLine(args, switchMappings);
```

To achieve something like:

```
--Logins:0=Login0 --Logins:1=Login1
```

But It seems not to work like that.

Is there a way to use switch mappings or any simpler syntax when passing array?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without `switchMappings` and change args like this:

```
//--Logins:0 Login0 --Logins:1 Login1
configBuilder.AddCommandLine(args);
var config=configBuilder.Build();
var logins= config.GetSection("Logins").GetChildren().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Tested and works fine.